# HTML form tag is taking new td space on IE

Tags: html

I am facing a browser issue. I need to create two "form" in which `<td>` is present. But problem is that after creating second "form" the `<td>` goes to new row. This problem is only on Internet Explorer not on Firefox.

Code is as follows:

```
<form name="myform" action="registerUser" onsubmit="return verifyEmail();" method="post">

<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left:2px;">
    <%
            String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");
        %>
        <input class="sign-in-textbox" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" onfocus="clearMessage(this,'Enter your work email address');" value="Enter your work email address" onblur="fillMessage(this,'Enter your work email address');"/>
        <br/>
</td>

</tr> 
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="49%" align="left" valign="middle"  style="padding-top:2px;">
    <input type="submit" class="p-signinbutton" id="register" value="Join" width="78"/>
    </td>
     </form>
     <form name="continueAsGuest" action="guestLogin.do" onsubmit="return continueAsGuest();" method="get">
    <td width="50%" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="submit" class="p-signinbutton" id="continueAsGuest" value="Continue as Guest" width="85"/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Why did you roll back to the broken formatting?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is not valid. Try moving the form tags inside the table elements. The second form is easily fixed with:

```
<td width="50%" align="left" valign="middle">
    <form name="continueAsGuest" action="guestLogin.do" onsubmit="return continueAsGuest();" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="p-signinbutton" id="continueAsGuest" value="Continue as Guest" width="85"/>
    </form>
</td>
```

The first one is harder to make valid, but it might work if you put the `<form>` tag inside the first `<td>` and the `</form>` tag one line higher inside the previous `<td>`.